# Remove duplicated words between two and more string texts in PHP

Tags: php, string

Words:

```
$word_1 = "My Subject Test Words Are Here"
$word_2 = "My Subject Different Word is there"
$word_3 = "My Subject Other Word is there"
```

In this words i want to remove "My Subject", the end of the day words should replaced like:

```
$word_1 = "Test Words Are Here"
$word_2 = "Different Word is there"
$word_3 = "Other Word is there"
```

My subject can be dynamically change it can be three word or four word.

Is it possible to remove first duplicated words from string?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the duplicate words by splitting it by space and convert into array then you can find the first match duplicate words

```
$words = [
  "My Subject Test Words Are Here",
  "My Subject Different Word is there",
  "My Subject Other Word is there"
];

$wordSplits = array_map(function($word) {
  return preg_split('/\s+/', $word, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
},$words);

$removeDuplicates = array_map(function($word) use($wordSplits) {
  return trim(str_replace(
    array_intersect(array_shift($wordSplits),...$wordSplits),
    '',
    $word
  ));
},$words);

var_dump($removeDuplicates);
```

Results:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "Test Words Are Here"
  [1]=>
  string(23) "Different Word is there"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "Other Word is there"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace` or `mb_str_replace` (for multibyte strings, e.g. containing non latinic symbols).

```
$result = str_replace('My Subject', '', $originString);
```

Comment: *"My subject can be dynamically change"*

Comment: My subject can be "My Other Subject"

Comment: Ok, this changes nothing. Put value which you want to replace into variable and do `str_replace($strToReplace, '', $originString)`

Comment: Or even put all possible values to replace into array and do 
`$toReplace = ['My subject', 'Another subject']; str_replace($toReplace, '', $originString);`

Comment: he said that he want to find duplicates from the strings